# Pros and Cons of CodeSmith

Tags: .net, code-generation, development-environment

I am new in [Codesmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) code generator tool. I don't know what are pros and cons of codesmith. I have some queries. Please help me to clear the use of codesmith.

What is advantage and disadvantage of codesmith?
What is alternative of Codesmith?
What is more the codesmith at please of Normal way of BAL,DAL development?

Answer (score 0):

I work for CodeSmith Tools. The overview page located [here](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) has some of the pros of using codesmith generator. CodeSmith Generator can generate any text markup based on a template. All of the templates that ship with Generator are open source and can be modified. I believe what you should be asking is what are the pros and cons of the various [template frameworks](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks).